# st_difference to each feature in sf object

Tags: r, dplyr, lapply, r-sf

Data available [here](https://swanseauniversity-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/j_a_h_jones_swansea_ac_uk/ESTEDVuH_xdMsM0jowcuA1YBvYI_1KqF3BL-w3H-kQHloQ?e=jOVl4i)

I have 2 large sf objects. One is an sf polygon object of buffered points and the other is an sf line object. I would like to difference the line object using the polygon object like so:

```
library(sf)

geopackage = 'differenceBIG.gpkg'

lines <- st_read(geopackage , layer = "lines")
points <- st_read(geopackage , layer = "points")

poly <- st_buffer(points, dist = 0.001)

differenced <- st_difference(lines, poly)
```

This take more than 3 days to complete (I gave up waiting); not good enough. Is there a way of differencing these large sf objects in a much shorter time? I'm using a PC with i7-6700 CPU @ 3.4 GHz and 32 GB of RAM.

**Update**: Turns out st_difference isn't the same as Difference in QGIS. I found the following in the sf.pdf document

```
# A helper function that erases all of y from x: 
st_erase = function(x, y) st_difference(x, st_union(st_combine(y)))

differenced <- st_erase(lines, poly)
```

Comment: Unable to reproduce. It took less than a minute on my machine. I'm guessing you have insufficient memory and were paging out to "virtual memory" on disk. Buy more memory.

Comment: That was just a sample dataset. Full size dataset uploaded.